# How to make Location header invalid, on 3xx redirect resulting in showing HTML

Tags: javascript

I came accross vulnerability where i can breakout in html body on 3xx redirect, my problem is that Location header is executed first means that html body is ignored.

```
<a href="https://example.com/"[INJECTION]/">here</a>
```

URL can be changed only after /

I actually found way to show html body if we redirect to mailto:test@gmail.com"[INJECTION]

but this is not my case.

If anyone knows way how to make Location header invalid i appericate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can put newlines (technically, the standard calls for a carriage return + new line pair) into the location header, you may be able to pull off a neat attack by injecting an entire false response into the server's response stream. Basically, add some random garbage (to defeat caching) and then terminate the Location header with a newline. At that point you can also control everything after the Location header, so you can specify `Connection: keep-alive`, `Content-Length: 0`, and two newlines in sequence to terminate the headers... and then

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: <date>
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: <length of payload>
Connection: close

<HTML><!-- arbitrary payload goes here --></HTML>
```

Your injected HTML will be executed on the client as same-origin. The server's actual response body will be thrown away as noise that came after the response body. This attack relies on the client being willing to treat a "response" it receives before sending the corresponding request as valid, but assuming it stopped parsing when it hit the first "complete" response (with 0 content length) and respected the connection keep-alive on that "response", the next thing it reads from the stream (which it will expect to be the server's response to the redirect-generated request) will be the arbitrary HTML you injected (which, for brevity, should probably be a single malicious script tag or similar).

Even if that doesn't work, header injection is good for some fun. You may be able to break the redirection by adding a second `Location:` header; some user-agents will try to follow the last location they see and if that one is invalid they will just render the body. You can definitely do things like inject your own cookies (works great if the site uses double-submit cookies for CSRF protection, for example; overwrite the CSRF cookie with a value you know and then make a CSRF attack against the victim).

You could also try injecting characters such as null bytes or other things that are not permitted in a URL or header to try and break the redirect; most of those won't wreck your message body too badly.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes!** If you also control the value of `Location` header. In short, if you provide an invalid port, say `x`, browsers don't follow the redirect and render the content if it has body.
Here's a demo -> https://cm2.pw/redirect?url=http://example.com:x&refresh

Interestingly, it also works with `mailto` URI as you said. So, if your injection goes beyond `/`, there aren't any possible ways, at least, not in modern browsers.